# How can I achieve this frosted-like effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, blur

I am trying to use Photoshop to create this effect:

[image: debian]

The original image can be any image, then I plan to apply a:

- blur effect
- semi-opaque white overlay

Is this correct? Is there a specific way to do this so the result is a close as possible to the image?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking the question to be honest. It sounds to me like you know how it was likely done or at least how to create that image yourself. The only thing missing is the photo that was used (if any). The closest you can get to replicating this exact image is by painting it as shown in user287001's answer. Unless you find the original image.

Answer (score 2):

Overlay is not needed. Here's a simple receipe. Check, if it's good enough.

Draw something over a white background layer:

[image]

Apply a heavy Gaussian Blur and reduce the brightness of the colors, if needed:

[image]

Write something:

[image]

Comment: I love how you started with the most crude basic MS Paint thing imaginable and it still gives a very similar effect!